# How to create .classpath and .project files to make a project compatible with Eclipse Helios?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am having a Java Web project with some class files, JSP files along with WEB-INF and META-INF folders. I want to use this project in Eclipse Helios.

For this I will need to import this project. However, Eclipse will search for .classpath and .project files in the root directory of the project. And unfortunately, I don't have these.

So, can I create one from the project?

Or do I just have to create one project and copy the files into the project? Though this will be a little tedious task if I have too many packages and class files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or do I just have to create one project and copy the files into the
>   project? Though this will be a little tedious task if I have too many
>   packages and class files.

It isn't tedious. Just create a blank Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and copy the source folder. You can add a "Source Folder" to point to where your Java source files are present. It will then automatically add all the packages under it.

Comment: I normally resort to the more hacky way of copying the `.classpath` and `.project` files from another project into this one. I just change the `<name>` of the project and refresh my workspace!